# Is it possible to split this kind of text documents into multiple ones with RegEx?

Tags: regex, text, split

I want to split one big text document (.txt) into multiple ones. This has been asked before but I think I need, in my case, a particular RegEx to do this task.

I have tried several "split" software but I have not found a satisfactory solution yet. The text document is a bunch of debates in the Spanish parliament. The text is divided into policy initiatives (I'm not sure if that is idiomatic) and I want to split it into a document per initiative.

The funny thing is that each initiative has its own title in the next form:

```
- DEL GRUPO PARLAMENTARIO CATALÁN (CONVERGÈNCIA I UNIÓ), REGULADORA DE LOS HORARIOS COMERCIALES. (Número de expediente 122/000004.)

- DEL DIPUTADO DON MARIANO RAJOY BREY, DEL GRUPO PARLAMENTARIO POPULAR EN EL CONGRESO, QUE FORMULA AL SEÑOR PRESIDENTE DEL GOBIERNO: ¿CÓMO VALORA USTED LOS PRIMEROS DÍAS DE SU GOBIERNO? (Número de expediente 180/000021.)
```

As you can see, every title is in upper case, it starts with a minus and ends with `XXX/XXXXXX.)` (where X is a digit), a dot and a close parenthesis.  Every title is different from each other. I have though making some RegEx to capture those characteristics in order to have a delimiter element between those debates, but I honestly can't figure out how to do it.

The ideal would be to select the title and the debate below it until another title appears and make a new document with that, so in the end I can have in a single document the policy initiative with its title and its own debate.

So, can this be done with the RegEx solution? What kind of software do I need to do this? Is Notepad++ enough?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple Awk attempt.

```
awk '/^- DEL .+ \(Número de expediente [1-9][0-9]*\/[0-9]+\.\)$/ {
        if (p) close (p)
        p = sprintf("split%05i.txt", ++i) }
    { print > p }' inputfile.txt
```

Your definition of "all uppercase" did not seem entirely well-defined so I cheated a bit; you might want to tweak my assumptions. Your Awk might not recognize `É` etc as upper case trivially, perhaps also depending on your locale.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have some problems to make it work, though. If I run your script it gives me some syntax error with the `0` and the `+`. I have changed that RegEx with the one @Opsse gave me: `^\-.+\d{3}\/\d{6}\.\)$`. Now it creates a new document but it's just identical to the input file so I don't know what am I doing wrong. I'm sorry if i'm bothering you. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: The `\d` regex won't work in Awk, it's in a different regex dialect, though it might work if you switch to `^-.+[0-9]{3}\/[0-9]{6}\.\)$`

Comment: Fixed the typo now, sorry (forgot to escape the backslash in the regex).

Comment: Oh yeah, it worked perfectly! I had to change the text format from DOS to UNIX and voilà! It worked! Thank you very much dude, I really appreciate it! Have a good one!

Comment: Awk can handle DOS files too, try `\r?$` instead of just `$`; though of course the proper fix is to not use DOS.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this RegEx to match the title:

```
^\-.+\d{3}\/\d{6}\.\)$
```

I assumed that the title always end with `XXX/XXXXXX.)` where `X` is a digit.

You can do a test with [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/0bUMbC/2), it also provide explanation about the syntax and you can export the code for some programming language.

Most text editor have a "RegEx" option with the find tool, but it could be not enough in some use case. Also almost any programming language can use RegEx.

Comment: That's nice! Indeed that RegEx helps a lot in order to capture these kind of titles. The ideal would be to select the title and the debate below it until another title appears and make a new document with that, so in the end I can have in a single document the policy initiative with its title and its own debate. Your comment is a very good start. And yeah you assumed it right, I have edited my post to make it clearer. Thank you very much!

Comment: For doing this you probably need to create a script with a programming language. I can't give you a general case since any implementation would be different.